# Linear Algebra Vector True and False Questions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a few true and false questions. I have explanations for them could someone please check them over?

1. $R^3$ contains two disjoint subspaces. I think this is true for example {1,2,3} and {4,5,6} are r3 but have nothing in common.
2. any 4 dimensional subspace of $L^{20}$ is isomorphic to R4. I think this is true because I can't find a set of vectors that doesn't satisfy f(a+b)= f(a)+f(b) and f(ab)=af(b)

3.A is a vector space and H=span{v1,v2,v3...vX} the dimension of A has to be X. I think this is false but I can't explain it.

4.Every linear transformation from r2 to r3 can be represent as any sort of transofrmation matrix. I think this is true because anything can be written as a matrix.

5.If Q is a 5 dimensional vector space. For every W greater than or equal to 5, there there is some k dimensional vector space E so that Q is isomorphic to subspace of E. I think this is true because k has to be greater than 5 so 5 will fall under a k dimension.

Comment: It's difficult to judge how much linear algebra you know. Do you know/can you use the fact that any vector space of dimension $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$? Do you know how to find the matrix of a linear transformation $V \to W$? Some of the things that you said are correct, but there are also a lot of mistakes, and you are a long way off providing a proof in those cases where you have asserted that the statement is true (or false).

Comment: As a starting point, note that every subspace contains the point 0 (why?). Does this contradict your answer for the first statement?

Comment: could you let me know which ones I got correct and which explanations are wrong?

Comment: Oh ok thanks, so 1 would be false because it is impossible to get a disjoint subspace because the zero vector has to be included in both subspaces which is an element in common

Comment: Yep. I will write an answer with some hints for the other questions. Maybe I was unfair in saying that there are lots of mistakes (the one you just pointed out was probably the only big one), but your proofs need some work.

Comment: No, it's ok you can be blunt with me, I am trying to self study this course before college

Answer (score 1):

1. False. Note that every subspace contains the point 0.
2. True. Use the more general fact that every vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$) of dimension $n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you haven't come across this theorem yet, try to prove it in your special case of $n=4$. (Take an arbitrary 4-dimensional vector space, and consider a basis for that space. Map the basis vectors onto the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$. Why is this an isomorphism?).
3. False. **Hint:** What is the dimension of $\text{span}\{(0,1), (0,2)\}$? (The answer is not 2. Can you generalise by finding a condition on the $x_i$ that makes statement 3 true? Think of the definition of a basis.)
4. True. It's true in general that every linear transformation between vector spaces can be expressed as a matrix.

   Take a basis $B_1$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and a basis $B_2$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Call your linear transformation $f$. The coefficients of the matrix you want (call it $F$) will be the image of the basis vectors in $B_1$, in terms of the basis vectors in $B_2$. Try to show as explicitly as possible that, $Fx=f(x)$ for every vector $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (the domain).

   In my opinion, the process of finding this matrix is quite confusing until you've seen it done many times (I have only provided a sketch of how it is done above). Perhaps you may wish to come back to this when you have a bit more experience under your belt.
5. True. This is similar to statement 2. You will need the fact that, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a vector space of dimension $n$. Can you see an obvious example? You will also need to be able to find a 5-dimensional subspace of a higher-dimensional vector space. **Hint:** take a basis, and consider a subset of that basis. How can you turn it into a subspace, and how can you control the dimension of your subspace?